# Python 2.7 installed in python 3.7 folder on my mac?

Tags: python

I somehow messed up python installation on my mac (osx mojave), and python seems installed on an incorrect folder. If I understand correctly, python 3.7 is installed in /usr/local/bin/python, but when I used command python, it runs 2.7, and command python3 runs python 3.8..

```
>>python --version
Python 2.7.10

>>which python
/usr/bin/python

>>ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snvplayer  admin  24 Aug 30 15:04 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.7

>>ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snvplayer  admin  24 Aug 30 15:04 /usr/local/bin/python ->
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snvplayer  admin  38 Aug 31 15:09 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snvplayer  admin  45 Aug 31 15:09 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snvplayer  admin  40 Aug 31 15:09 /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snvplayer  admin  47 Aug 31 15:09 /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8-config
```

when I just run python, the version is 2.7.10

on my bash_profile the path is set as following

```
>>nano ~/.bash_profile
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

I just want to be able to run python 3.x with python command, not python3..

Would running the command below do the trick?
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

If you are using Linux, add the following  `~/.bashrc alias python=python3` Restart the shell and type python and python3 should start instead of python2.

Answer (score 0):

it was the recommendation that `python` remains a link to `python2` (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#application-to-the-cpython-reference-interpreter)